# How to add white space between two values in a Pug mixin

Tags: pug

I'm making a Pug mixin, i'm concatenating to values, but can't separate the two with a white space.

```
mixin label(address)
   .name=address.firstName+address.lastName
   .address= address.houseNumber
   .city= address.city+address.state
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Pug's [string interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#string-interpolation-escaped) syntax:

```
mixin label(address)
    .name #{address.firstName} #{address.lastName}
    .address #{address.houseNumber}
    .city #{address.city}, #{address.state}
```

Note the space between the two variables in `.name` and the comma and space in `.city`.